# How to determine how big the Request.Form object is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

I am making a web service and a portion of it includes enforcing different maximum form sizes on different pages.

Other than running through the Form object and doing a `.Length` on all of the strings, is there a clean way of quickly determining the size of the submitted form values? Particularly in the context of a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an ASMX web service? Then what about [Request.TotalBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c98h219s.aspx)?